# Unable to send email from a codeignitor project in the live server but working in localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

The error that I am getting

> severity : Warning
> Message: fsockopen(): Unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection refused)
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php

This is my controller function:

```
    public function contactload(){
        // to load the register.php     
        // here the data is stored to database
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        //storing the data into the array
        $formArray =array();
        $formArray['name']= $this->input->post('name');
        $formArray['email']= $this->input->post('email');
        $formArray['country']= $this->input->post('country');
        $formArray['subject']= $this->input->post('subject');
    
        // calling the create function in user_model
        $check=$this->User_model->create($formArray);
        if($check==true){
            if ($this->User_model->sendEmail($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('name')))
        {
            // successfully sent mail
            echo '<script>alert("Mail Is sent kindly check the Mail")</script>';
        } else {
            // error
            echo '<script>alert("UNABLE TO SEND THE MAIL")</script>';
        }
    }else{
        echo "error !";
    }


}
```

And the model:

```
public function sendEmail($to_email,$name) { 
    $from_email = '*********@gmail.com'; //change this to yours 
    $subject = 'Your meaasge Has Sucessfully reached Us'; 
    $message = ' <html> <head> <title>Conformation Mail</title> </head> <body>
    
    $this->load->library('email'); 
    $config = Array(
            'protocol'  => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => '465',
            'smtp_user' => '***************@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => '****************',
            'mailtype'  => 'html',
            'smtp_timeout' => '60',
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
            'wordwrap'  => TRUE,
            'newline'   => "\r\n"
    );
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->initialize($config);
   
    
    //send mail
    $this->email->from($from_email);
    $this->email->to($to_email);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);
    return $this->email->send();
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

The mail sending operation is working on localhost  But not working in the live server

It is a code ignitor project

Comment: Why you ALL load a library without a config, then reload with a config and then initialize with the same config?? Anyway....initialize the _smtp_crypto_ Mail instance variable to "ssl", remove the "ssl://" from the _smtp_host_, set the _smtp_auth_ to true, then retry in live and tell us ifsomething changes

Comment: No Changes In its action  . Is that is not a right way to initialize or load the library

Comment: Fine. Is the "live" server behind a proxy? Are the relevant outgoing ports open? Are there a local smtpd, like postfix or sendmail?

Comment: No it's not the right way. For almost all the built in libraries in Ci v3, you have to build your configuration, like you do, then call the load passing the parameters. Internally Ci does all the job involving creating the new instance, initializing with your config. So it's better to have first the **$config = Array(** ... then call the **$this->load->library('email',$config);** and nothing else, no more loading for the same library

Comment: If it works on your local host but not the live server, check the 465 port is open on your live server. You could also switch to port 587 using TLS instead of SSL;         $config['smtp_host']    = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com'; $config['smtp_port']    = '587';

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variable in order to get the Address of the Server.

In The Controller you have to do something like the following:

```php
public function SendEmail()
{
    $email = $this->input->post('email');

    $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>Conformation Mail</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <h1>Hello </h1>
                        <h3>New User</h3>
                        <p>tO cHECK THE EMAIL SENT  </p>
                        <p>Thank Your.</p>
                    </body>
                </html>';
    //Sending email from localhost or live server
    $localhosts = array(
        '::1',
        '127.0.0.1',
        'localhost'
    );
        
    $protocol = 'mail';
    if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $localhosts)) {
        $protocol = 'smtp';
    }

    $config = array(
        'protocol' => $protocol,
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '**************@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '***************',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'starttls'  => true,
        'newline'   => "\r\n",
    );

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from("************@gmail.com");
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject("New user contacts");
    $this->email->message($message);
    $flag = $this->email->send();

    if($flag){
        echo "Email sent";
        echo '<script>alert("email sent")</script>';
        $this->load->view('main');
    }else{
        echo "Email sending failed";
        echo '<script>alert("mail not sent")</script>';
        $this->load->view('main');
    }
}
```

Now use the controller function to send the email.